# Android 6, delete file from /data/user/0/

Tags: linux

I have an un-rooted Samsung Galaxy running Android 6.0.1 and for an app to work properly, I must delete a (lock-)file from the following path:

/data/user/0/com.some.app/some.dir/lkc904d56b5dbe600e60d121882bb2a1f2

How can I delete that file (without rooting the device)?

Thanx a lot for your help!

BR,
D.

PS: I tried mounting the device storage to my Ubuntu 16.04 machine, but could not find the folder.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way you can access the `/data` partition **unless you are *rooted***.

So, you need to root the device again to delete it..

Or, if you have a custom recovery installed, then you can just easily delete it, like:

1. For TWRP, open 'Advanced' and go to 'File Manager' and delete the file.
2. For CWM/Philz, just use (flash) the [AROMA Filemanager Zip](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1646108) and browse & delete the file.
3. Or else, you could create a flashable zip to delete the file from the exact file location, or you could do it from the Terminal of the custom recovery (if it provides one)

Or else, if you don't have custom recovery, and if you don't want to root, the only way would be to **factory reset** (you might want to take backups before that).

> PS: I tried mounting the device storage to my Ubuntu 16.04 machine, but could not find the folder.

The device storage (internal storage) shows the files under `/data/media/0`, so you won't see it there..